# How to make two columns using <div>

Tags: android, html

I want to show the my webpage as ##TITLE##              ##VALUE##
My Html is

```
<div> 
 <div style="padding:8px; border: 1px solid black; color:#006BF2; width: 90px;">##TITLE##</div> 
 <div style="padding:8px; border: 1px solid black; color:#000000; text-align:left; ">##VALUE##</div> </div>
```

Now it is shown as

```
 ##TITLE##
 ##VALUE##
```

I know only basics of html.How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `float: left` both DIVs. `overflow: auto` on their parent.

Comment: My first column having width of 90px.And the second column need to be occupy remaining width

Comment: What about heights? Is the height of the wrapper, or the columns, fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `float: left` style for your `title` and `value` columns.
Below them set new empty div with `clear: both` style.

```
<div> 
 <div style="float: left; padding:8px; border: 1px solid black; color:#006BF2; width: 90px;">##TITLE##</div> 
 <div style="float: left; padding:8px; border: 1px solid black; color:#000000; text-align:left; ">##VALUE##</div>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have need to set float property for this.
one div should be float left and another should be right like below.

for first div set style => style="float: left; width: 50%;
for second div set style => style="float: right; width: 50%;

Comment: First column having width 90px is fixed.